# What books do you recommend I should use as an introduction to convex analysis?

Tags: reference-request, convex-analysis, book-recommendation

A few years ago, I was in undergrad taking an introductory real analysis course. There was a problem I could not solve. I went to the TA. He was able to solve it using convexity. He recommended that I study convexity. What books do you recommend I should use as an introduction to convex analysis?

Comment: Bauschke and Combettes

Comment: R.T. Rockafellar

Comment: Are you interested in convex analysis more for applications in convex optimization or as subject in pure mathematics?

Answer (score 1):

A general reference for working with convexity (i.e. convex functions + sets) is chapters 1 and 2 of Boyd and Vandenberghe. It's available for free on Boyd's website.

Comment: Although I'd agree with you that this is a good choice for someone who wants to use convex analysis in optimization, and that the book is accessible to graduate students in most science and engineering fields, it's not a very good choice for someone who wants to do convex analysis as a topic in pure mathematics.